# Indexing several DBs in lucene (and performance on low cardinality fields)

Tags: lucene, database-performance

I have to index several relational DBs in a Lucene index (for value-based searching). 
Some searches will be for values from a specific DB and others will be for values from all DBs.

I can think of two ways to implement this:

1. Create one big index and add a field called database_id. Use this field when querying over some specific DB.
2. Create an index for every DB. When querying one DB, I will direct the query to just one index, when querying all DBs I'll use MultiReader that runs query on all indices.

Option 2 seems more comfortable to me because of easier maintenence and faster querying when querying just one DB. Also I came across several posts that say low-cardinality fields are not good for lucene performance (can someone shed light on this? is this true?).

I'd like to hear community thoughts, what other pros and cons can be?